# RestAPI or any other methods for pulling data from Cacti

Tags: cacti

Is there a way we can get data(like interface utilization data of routers)  from Cacti server remotely?
I did come accross some answers which said using rrdtool export options,but i was wondering if there was a way to do it without touching the rrd's?I would be using a linux server to remotely access this data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no RESTAPI for CACTI, however you can pull the details from the database tables